# How can I run 2 task on reboot at 10 min apart in ubuntu

Tags: cron, reboot

I am trying to run 2 tasks at reboot on Ubuntu VPS. I know that I can setup crontab job for it, by doing 
"@reboot Taks1"
"@reboot Taks2"
But what I want is to run the 1st task at reboot and 2nd task 10 min after reboot.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please follow the NOT ACCEPTED answer. Add your script as an action after the services that need to be up are up.